# French terminology for web-based platform

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, informatique

Does anyone know how I would say the following in French?

1. permission-controlled location
2. version-controlled environment

Direct translation seems off.

Thanks

Comment: For 1, what is the specific sense of "location" ? For 2, you may say "environnement versionné".

Answer (score 2):

In my view of French native and web-developper I would suggest:

- Emplacement autorisé
- environnement à gestion de versions

Answer (score 2):

- Zone sécurisée / zone soumise à contrôle d'accès
- Environnement sous gestion de configuration, de version(s) / Environnement versionné